# World where the Nazis won. Features "Stappers" (the Gestapo) and "Ceepies" (Communist Party)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for story set in a future world in which the Nazis won World War II. The main character mentions 'stappers' (gestapo) and 'ceepies' (communist party) and schism of mark (Marxism).

I read it  over thirty years ago and can’t remember title or author. It was in an anthology of short stories, possibly edited by Isaac Asimov

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/231083/society-with-standardized-english-language (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 11):

Could this be Anthony Boucher's *[[The] Barrier](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?93591)*?

> The first difficulty was with language.
> That is only to be expected when you jump five hundred years; but it is nonetheless perplexing to have your first casual query of: “What city is this?” answered by the sentence: “**Stappers will get you. Or be you Slanduch?**”
> It was significant that the first word John Brent heard in the State was “Stappers.” But Brent could not know that then. It was only some hours later and fifty years earlier that he learned the details of the Stapper system. At the moment all that concerned him was food and plausibility.

I can't see any mention of "ceepies" though.

Comment: That's definitely the beginning of Barriers, by Boucher. It was one of Six Great Novels of Science Fiction published as a collection in the 1950s. I believe the guess about Asimov is correct. "Slanduch" was the form, 500 years in the future, to which "Auslandeutsch" (sp?) had devolved. "Be you Slanduch?" illustrates the elimination of all irregular verbs from English. "What city is this?" includes an irregular form of the infinitive "to be," and is verboten; Slanduch were given some leeway, but Stappers apparently arrested citizens using such verb forms.